# Discord Connection to MongoDB (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I am currently building a Discord Bot, and I am facing this error when I am trying to get the code to connect to MongoDB.

> 0[CONTENT_TYPE_INVALID]: Expected "Content-Type" header to be one of {'application/json'}.
> at SequentialHandler.runRequest (/Users/jinghenggg/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.cjs:287:15)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/Users/jinghenggg/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
> at async REST.request (/Users/jinghenggg/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/REST.cjs:52:22) {
> rawError: {
> code: 50035,
> errors: { _errors: [Array] },
> message: 'Invalid Form Body'
> },
> code: 50035,
> status: 400,
> method: 'PUT',
> url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/1007133286025404477/guilds/905109232985190440/commands',
> requestBody: { files: undefined, json: undefined }
> }

The codes in question are as follows...

```js
client.once('ready', async () => {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { keepAlive: true })
    console.log('Live on server!');

    if (interaction.member.roles.cache.some(roles => roles.name === `Baby`)) {
        //insert to DB
        setTimeout(async () => {
            new testSchema({
                ID: '1',
                username: 'spidermin#4322',
                address: '0x2134010'
            }).save
        }, 1000);

        await interaction.reply({ 
            content: `Congrats <@${interaction.user.id}>!`, 
            ephemeral: true 
        });
    }
});
```

Is this code affecting this error? I have no idea why this code will bring about a 'Invalid Form Body' but this is the only code I have added before the error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly about `mongoose` the [keepAlive](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) makes the mongoose connection to delay. And there's a problem about delaying the connection. You might get the error about: `Debuffer` something.

So I suggest to you to change your way of connecting your mongoose to discordbot:

```js
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { keepAlive: true })
```

To:

```js
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true})
```